# JWTAuth no genera token - laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, cors, jwt

Buen dia estoy haciendo una app de laravel y estoy configurando el JWT antes de eso cree mi propio AuthServiceProvider personalizado y en el archivo auth.php lo configure. ahora tengo un problema

```
 try {
            $token = JWTAuth::attempt(['correo' => $correo, 'contrasena' => $clave]);
            log::alert('JWTAuth::attempt');
            log::alert($token);
        
            if (!$token) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 401, 'text' => ['message' => 'Credenciales incorrectas']], 401);
            }
        
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
            log::alert('Error al generar el token JWT');
            log::alert($e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['status' => 500, 'text' => ['message' => 'Error al generar el token JWT']], 500);
        }
```

este es el codigo que estoy colocando para poder hacer el login pero no me trae ningun token al hacer un log me trae vacio ya verifique este correcta la informacion en la base y en lo que estoy enviando

quedo atento a sus comentarios muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias razones por las cuales puede no estar funcionando, te comparto las mas comunes:

Revisa la generacion de la clave secreta de JWT, ejecutando el comando `php artisan jwt:secret` en tu terminal. valida que se corrio correctamente.

Verifica que en tu archivo config/auth.php tengas configurado el guard con el driver jwt. Algo similar a esto:

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Asegúrate de que el proveedor de usuarios (normalmente users) esté configurado correctamente en config/auth.php.

El modelo de usuario (usualmente User.php) debe implementar `Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject`. Además, debes incluir las funciones getJWTIdentifier y getJWTCustomClaims. Confirma que las credenciales (correo y contrasena) correspondan a las columnas correctas en tu base de datos. Por defecto, Laravel usa email y password. Si utilizas nombres de columna diferentes, asegúrate de que tu modelo de usuario y tu intento de autenticación coincidan con estos nombres.

Después de cambiar cualquier configuración, ejecuta `php artisan config:cache` para refrescar la configuración del sistema.